# What is the best way of displaying rapidly changeddatabase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, node.js

I have a database that keeps receiving new information every second, and I want to have a dynamic changing display for this database on a WebSite.

What is the best platform to go with? And where could I start looking? I'm open for anything, AJAX, JQuery, Node.JS, etc. I just have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the best way to go will be:

- Knockout.js (Or angularJS, but knockout syntax is much cleaner)
- And server side library like SignalR on .net.

If you cannot use .net, look for any websockets library in your language. 
I use it every day and get awesome results! (Like updating only one field instead of all table, sending message on wrong update, etc)
Hope this helps

PS: Web sockets are designed to handle hard load (Up to real time FPS gaming)

Answer (score 0):

You could do up a node.js server using http://socket.io/ for transport.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Client

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Socket IO uses websockets if available, and falls back to other methods if not.